# V-IF and V-for Loop conditional with select options seems to be never entering the v-else statement

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

So I was wondering why this v-if and v-else statement did not work and why I to tackle it a different way.

The code is as follows

```
<select v-else v-model="experiment.workflow" required>
    <option selected :value="null">Required: Select a Workflow {{ isChain ? 'Chain' : '' }}</option>
    <option
     v-if="isWorkflowChain"
     v-for="workflow of data.workflows"
     :key="workflow.uuid"
     :value="workflow"
         {{ workflow.head.name }}>
    </option>
    <option
     v-else
     v-for="workflow of data.workflowChains"
     :key="workflow.uuid"
     :value="workflow"
     </option>
```

So I was given this piece of code and it looks like when loading in the data in the v-if statement was fine and the values showed in the drop down menu. When I set the value to

```
export default {
    props: {
         isWorkflowChain: {
             type: Boolean
             value: false
             }
        }
    }
```

What should have occurred was that it should have skipped the v-if element and head into the v-else (Which I believe it does) and populate the data but the v-for statement doesn't populate the data. From first glance does anyone have any thoughts as to why?

Comment: `wf === 'workflowChains' `?

Comment: well the wf variable could be anything except 'Workflow'. In the for data returned  I assigned wf to 'workflowChains'.

Comment: What I mean is that in `v-if` it expects a boolean, so you need `===` instead of `=`?

Comment: `wf = 'workflow'` need this to be a `==` or `===` as well.

Comment: I changed the value to a boolean instead so that's what is expecting. If true it enters into that v-if statement. If False it should head into the v-else statement and then start iterating through the for-loop (still doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a valid question, since it's not obvious that a mix of `v-for` with `v-else` is currently not supported.

*note the closed feature request at*
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4174

### Reason

The problem is that `v-for` has higher priority and therefor is handled first, and `v-if` is handled second. That means, not only is the v-if executed on every item, but more importantly in the context of this question, it cannot access the `v-else` outside of the `v-for`.

Read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

### Solution

The correct way would be isolate the two blocks, and put the `v-if` on a higher level, non-rendering `<template>` component.

```html
<option>
  <template v-if="isWorkflowChain">
    <option v-for/>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <option v-for/>
  </template>
</option>
```

The quicker way to do it is to use an opposite conditional (`!isWorkflowChain`) with a `v-for` like this though.

```html
<select v-else v-model="experiment.workflow" required>
     <option selected :value="null">Required: Select a Workflow {{ isChain ? 'Chain' : '' }}</option>
     <option
         v-if="isWorkflowChain"
         v-for="workflow of data.workflows"
         :key="workflow.uuid"
         :value="workflow"
     >{{ workflow.head.name }}</option>
     <option
         v-if="!isWorkflowChain"
         v-for="workflow of data.workflowChains"
         :key="workflow.uuid"
         :value="workflow"
     >{{ workflow.head.name }}</option>
</select>
```

and you can make `isWorkflowChain` a computed. If you have multiple statements and want to capture the else, it gets a bit trickier, but you can put that logic into a computed.

Answer (score 1):

### Vue 3 - Breaking Change

In Vue 3 `v-if` will have higher precedence than `v-for`:

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-if-v-for.html#overview

---

**Computed Properties**

However, it is recommended to avoid using both on the same element, and instead of dealing with this at the template level, one method for accomplishing this is to create a computed property that filters out a list for the visible elements:

```
computed: {
  isWorkflowChain: () => {
    // do filtering
  }
}
```

Template

```
<option v-for="workflow in isWorkflowChain">
    {{ workflow.head.name }}
</option>
```

Docs: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-if-v-for.html#introduction

Answer (score 0):

you need to close `<option>`, forget `>` of `v-if` option :

your code :

```
<option
   v-if="wf = 'workflow'"
   v-for="workflow of data.workflows"
   :key="workflow.uuid"
   :value="workflow"  // here where `>` is missing
      {{ workflow.head.name }}
</option>
```

what it's should be :

```
<option
   v-if="wf = 'workflow'"
   v-for="workflow of data.workflows"
   :key="workflow.uuid"
   :value="workflow">
     {{ workflow.head.name }}
</option>
```

Comment: Sorry I might have mistyped that as well into my question. Thank you for pointing that out.